# SymPy Comparison and Conditional

Tags: python, sympy

What is the SymPy equivalent of the Mathematica function: `f[x_]:=If[x==Infinity,1,2]`?

If tried without success:

```
lambdify(x,Piecewise((1, <expr> ),(2,True))
```

where `<expr>` is one of

1)

```
 Eq(x,oo)
```

2)

```
 simplify(x)==oo
```

3)

```
 Eq(x+1,x)
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct expression should be `Piecewise((1, Eq(x, 0)), (2, True))`. `==` does structural comparison and does not create a symbolic object (see http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#equals-signs).

This works for me

```
In [3]: f = lambdify(x, Piecewise((1, Eq(x, 0)), (2, True)))

In [4]: f(0)
Out[4]: 1

In [5]: f(1)
Out[5]: 2
```

Comment: yes this works. I actually tried to solve another problem (see updated question), and thought that the original question was demonstrating the problem, when in fact it was not. sorry